# Problem with AC power supply in Proteus 8

Tags: power-supply, power, ac

I'm working on a simulation where I am using transformers, rectifier circuit, relay and voltage controlled switch. My problem is basically setting up my AC power source for the transformer. I have tried using the sine generator, AC voltage source and AC current source. I have also edited the amplitudes, frenquency and phase shift but when I run my simulation, and I check the value of the source, it is reading zero all through. My voltage, current and power is zero and this is not allowing my circuit to run properly.

Can anyone pls tell me how my AC supply can produce good values?

Comment: What values have you set for the source parameters? Also try driving the transformer via a 0.1 ohm resistor. It could be a problem that some sims don't like voltage sources directly connected to inductors.

Comment: Thanks but maybe I should upload some pictures

Answer (score 1):

What sim are you using? If you are using LTSpice (what I use for simulation) it should be just fine.
I would try putting a very low resistance between the source and transformer, this usually kicks the thing back into working.

Also, have you tried putting a DC value straight through an inductor? If the sim then shows zero it thinks there is a dead short, try a low value resistor or a diode, and keep in mind that the component you use to seperate the source from the transformer will not be there irl.